# Trust Law - do trustees have to confirm that you are a beneficiary of the trust if you ask them directly?

Tags: australia, trusts-and-estates

I've asked the trustees of a trust to confirm that I am a beneficiary, which is what I believe to be the case.  Do they have to give an honest answer?

Comment: What jurisdiction are you talking about? It may affect the answer. I am aware of (at least historically) setting up secret trusts to support and legitimize bastard children post-death (and avoid scandal and social stigma in the decedent's lifetime).

Comment: The jurisdiction is Australia. Thanks.